# Manipulate svg colors with css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have made a `svg` icon for search in illustrator, and want to use it in my website. I have place it in the html can see the icon.

```
<div id="search-btn">
    <img src="svg/search.svg">
</div>
```

But since I made it in black, I want to change the color of the magnifiying glass and the background. How do I manipulate the colors of the svg using css? I am very new to svg and your help will be very valuable. Thank you.

search icon:

[image]

svg code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_10_" d="M98.2,89.7L63,54.5c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c4-5.6,6.3-12.4,6.3-19.8c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4
    c-19,0-34.4,15.4-34.4,34.4c0,19,15.4,34.4,34.4,34.4c7.3,0,14-2.3,19.6-6.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l35.2,35.2
    c2.4,2.4,6.2,2.4,8.5,0l0,0C100.6,95.9,100.6,92.1,98.2,89.7z M7.3,34.5c0-15.1,12.3-27.4,27.4-27.4c15.1,0,27.4,12.3,27.4,27.4
    c0,15.1-12.3,27.4-27.4,27.4C19.6,61.9,7.3,49.6,7.3,34.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments on this answer

> CSS does not apply cross-document and the img is a separate document.
>   Images must be self contained in a single file to preserve privacy. –
>   Robert Longson

So this means you won't be able to include your `SVG` in your `img` tag and customize it using `CSS` on the page. So you have two options:

Inline the `SVG` code, which means scrapping the `img` tag. You can then target the `SVG` as below.

```css
#search-btn svg {
  fill: blue;
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="search-btn">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="XMLID_10_" d="M98.2,89.7L63,54.5c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c4-5.6,6.3-12.4,6.3-19.8c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4
    c-19,0-34.4,15.4-34.4,34.4c0,19,15.4,34.4,34.4,34.4c7.3,0,14-2.3,19.6-6.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l35.2,35.2
    c2.4,2.4,6.2,2.4,8.5,0l0,0C100.6,95.9,100.6,92.1,98.2,89.7z M7.3,34.5c0-15.1,12.3-27.4,27.4-27.4c15.1,0,27.4,12.3,27.4,27.4
    c0,15.1-12.3,27.4-27.4,27.4C19.6,61.9,7.3,49.6,7.3,34.5z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Or you could add styles to the `SVG` file itself, as below, but this is similar to simply editing the file in Illustrator to get the colours you want.

```html
<div id="search-btn">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
      <style>
        #XMLID_10_ {
          fill: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <path id="XMLID_10_" d="M98.2,89.7L63,54.5c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c4-5.6,6.3-12.4,6.3-19.8c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4
    c-19,0-34.4,15.4-34.4,34.4c0,19,15.4,34.4,34.4,34.4c7.3,0,14-2.3,19.6-6.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l35.2,35.2
    c2.4,2.4,6.2,2.4,8.5,0l0,0C100.6,95.9,100.6,92.1,98.2,89.7z M7.3,34.5c0-15.1,12.3-27.4,27.4-27.4c15.1,0,27.4,12.3,27.4,27.4
    c0,15.1-12.3,27.4-27.4,27.4C19.6,61.9,7.3,49.6,7.3,34.5z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: But he's not using an inline SVG he's using an external file via an image. Why not suggest an img solution e.g. put a rect in the SVG file itself to create a background?

Comment: @RobertLongson can you use fill to target SVG in img tags?

Comment: If you put it in the SVG file itself you can. I.e. edit the image file and embed a `<style>` tag in it with the fill you want. You'd need a rect to target the fill to as you can't use background. Or you could just add a `<rect fill="whatever"...`>` to the image file itself.

Comment: @RobertLongson ah yes ok - what I thought. The thing is, the way I interpreted the OPs question was he want to be able to change the colour without changing the file. Seeing as your knowledge of SVG couldn't be greater (yes I checked ur profile) I'm guessing it would be impossible with an external file.

Comment: CSS does not apply cross-document and the img is a separate document. images must be self contained in a single file to preserve privacy.

Answer (score 1):

To set the `background-color` of your `<svg>` you have to use the `background` or `background-color` property. To set the color of the icon you have to use the `fill` property. See the following example:

```css
svg {
  background:yellow;
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_10_" d="M98.2,89.7L63,54.5c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c4-5.6,6.3-12.4,6.3-19.8c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4
    c-19,0-34.4,15.4-34.4,34.4c0,19,15.4,34.4,34.4,34.4c7.3,0,14-2.3,19.6-6.1c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l35.2,35.2
    c2.4,2.4,6.2,2.4,8.5,0l0,0C100.6,95.9,100.6,92.1,98.2,89.7z M7.3,34.5c0-15.1,12.3-27.4,27.4-27.4c15.1,0,27.4,12.3,27.4,27.4
    c0,15.1-12.3,27.4-27.4,27.4C19.6,61.9,7.3,49.6,7.3,34.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: background and background-colour will only work if the SVG is embedded in a html page. You'd need an explicit rect for a standalone SVG like the OP has.

Answer (score -1):

You could use classes for svg elements.
Adobe Illustrator for example offers the possibility to create SVG internal CSS.
But you can also write the style definitions in your own stylesheet.

To set the background use the `fill` property, like sebastianbrosch mentioned.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .orange {
                fill:#f66d00;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <path class="orange" d="M98.2, ... ,34.5z"/>
</svg>
```